# How to add multi line string property on DSL

Tags: dsl, dsl-tools, visual-studio-designer

I am developing a workflow designer by DSL tools (Domain Specific Language) in Visual Studio,

I want to add a multi line string property as a domain property on one of my domain classes.

When I add it as string, it's only 1 line of string.

This is what I am looking for, something like Notes in DSL designer.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, in case somebody else is looking for it too.

So we need to add `UITypeEditor`, by adding this as `CustomAttribute` on domain property

```
[System.ComponentModel.Editor(
            typeof(System.ComponentModel.Design.MultilineStringEditor),
            typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))]
```

Also `System.design.dll` should be added to solution too

More info at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512860.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396